# Name of log file where boot process is logged

Tags: linux, boot, logging, centos-5

I'm using CentOS 5.3.  After booting up, where can I find the log file that contains if all services where successfully loaded or not?

For example when computer boots you get a list of start services and they can be OK or FAILED.

Is there a log file where this information is kept? I had a look in the following directory /var/log/ but not sure which one will contain the informaiton that I need.

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two places to look:

Run `dmesg`. From its man page "dmesg is used to examine or control the kernel ring buffer. The program helps users to print out their bootup messages."

Look in `/var/log/messages`

Comment: This answer helped me get to the right directory.  Running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and I had to do a `$ ls -alt /var/log` which showed me all the log files available with newest ones listed first.  After that I could cat any of the files and go through them.

Answer (score 4):

You may also have a /var/log/boot.log file. It depends on whether local7.* was configured in /etc/syslog.conf.

Comment: on my centos 7 that's at /etc/rsyslog.conf

Comment: @sdjuan  Correct. CentOS moved to `rsyslog` in version 6